# Не получается подключить conn pool asyncpg через unix сокеты к базе PostgreSQL. Пишет при подключении, что файл не найден

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg

Есть клиент на python, который использует пул соединений через asyncpg. Клиент и PostgreSQL запущены на одном сервере Linux. При попытке подключения возникает ошибка, что такой файл не найден.

URI:

```
postgresql:///devdb?host=/var/run/postgresql&user=maxidev&password=j2v4j23324v242h34v2hj&port=5432
```

Ошибка:

```
File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 2260, in create_unix_connection
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 2255, in uvloop.loop.Loop.create_unix_connection
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

pg_hba:

```
local    devdb     maxidev             all                 md5
```

Comment: Так а база запущена? С синтаксически некорректным pg_hba база не стартует, если что. А у вас именно синтаксическая ошибка - у `local` не бывает адреса.

Comment: С этими значениями она перезапускается без проблем

Comment: Логи щас посмотрел: 2022-09-05 13:38:54.501 +05 [26385] maxidev@devdb FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "maxidev"
2022-09-05 13:38:54.501 +05 [26385] maxidev@devdb DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "local   all             all                                     peer"

Answer (score 0):

Проблему исправил тем, что убрал all - поле ADDRESS у local и убрал ранее определённое разрешение:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```